# Vuelidate Validate Based on Two Fields

Tags: vue.js, vuelidate

In Vue, I have to fields: date and time. I want to create a custom validator and assign it to the time field. The custom validator should check that the time is in the future. This validator will depend on the time value and the date value. In other words, the user enters a date and a time, and I need to check if that combination is in the future. How do I create a custom validator that depends on two fields?